# dyld: Library not loaded, Reason: image not found

Tags: macos, gdb, shared-libraries

I used gdb normally until this week. Now running gdb I see:

```
(gdb) r
Starting program: /Volumes/MyProg 
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libCore.so
  Referenced from: /Volumes/MyProg
  Reason: image not found
(gdb)
```

How to fix it?

I have:

- OSX 10.9
- GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6 installed with MacPorts

P.S.

I have reinstalled gdb and Xcode. This does not help.

I see a lot of questions about dyld issues, but obviously I lack experience with libraries on OSX, and they appears to be useless for me.

For example this topic: [dyld issues library not loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449468/dyld-issues-library-not-loaded)
But how to download library again?

Or this topic: [Dyld: Library not loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794737/dyld-library-not-loaded)
But how to find out install name? What is `@rpath`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How I fixed it:

1. `libCore.so` is a library from [ROOT framework](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/discovering-root), which `MyProg` uses.
2. If I understand correctly, the message `Library not loaded: @rpath/libCore.so   Referenced from: /Volumes/MyProg   Reason: image not found` means that linker found the library, but can't use it.
3. Root, during installation uses clang by default. Meanwhile as I prefer gcc and `MyProg` uses gcc.
4. I have reinstalled root with gcc compiler:

   ./configure --with-cxx=g++ --with-cc=gcc --with-ld=g++
5. I have recompiled `MyProg`.

and now I can debug it with gdb.

Answer (score 29):

I solved this issue with "Embedded Binaries" in the General project settings.

Comment: yes this worked with Carthage.  The Carthage instructions (as of 5/23/2015) state to add to linked libraries - but I deleted that and added it through embedded binaries. It then (on its own) appeared in linked libraries. Now all works.

Answer (score 11):

i have solved this issue by changing the following settings

Go to Project Setting Your_Target->General->Embedded Binaries-> Click on + button and add your library here

Comment: try this one but not working  how it possible remove  not found image error

Answer (score 1):

You can find more information about rpath here: [link](http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2009/11/15/rpath/)

So you need to point the path to your libCore.so, but honestly I have not faced with this library so I don't know where is it located.

You can check also this answer to understand what it is rpath: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464149/linking-is-jacked-up-wtf-is-rpath-macos-x)

Comment: I saw this link. But it feels like it describe something for XCode developers and I miss very basics. The link does not answer the question how to find the value of @rpath...  I see that I can find value in some windows named Target Info, but I have not idea how to find these windows.....

Comment: I have added new link in answer maybe it will be useful for you. Please check answer.

Comment: is this helpful answer? i think if not you need to wait some programers that already faced with the same problem like in your case.

Comment: @kim123 or you can dart bounty for this question

Comment: ok can you answer on your question, because it will be helpful for someone who has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

For Xcode 11 or above, there is another simpler solution which worked for me if you are using Cocoapods.

In your Podfile, add use_frameworks! after your Target line like this -

```
target 'YourAppName' do
  use_frameworks!
```

Basically it adds all your pods as a framework in your framework folder.