# dyld_l_fatal_error when Running app on device but not simulator after iOS 9.2.1 update on device

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios-simulator

I've been banging my head against the walls with this one. I recently updated my iPhone 6S to iOS 9.2.1 and since then I get the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/AMScrollingNavbar.framework/AMScrollingNavbar
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/EB384B23-1BCC-4E23-8FB7-E0349C4F52B9/Qanda.app/Qanda
  Reason: image not found
```

The weird thing is not only is it running on the simulator but AMScrollingNavbar was installed with cocoapods then removed… So it shouldn't even be trying to search for it.

I have tried multiple things non of which have worked:

- cleaned the project
- restarted xCode
- reset the Pods
- deleted the App from the device and reinstalled
- followed all these steps: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/25352
- also tried this [how to ENABLE_BITCODE in xcode 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31205133/how-to-enable-bitcode-in-xcode-7)

Thanks!

Comment: see this link it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24993752/os-x-framework-library-not-loaded-image-not-found

Comment: and this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20455492/dyld-library-not-loaded-reason-image-not-found

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik: thanks but non of the above worked. Same error

Comment: whats your Xcode version ? if its less then 7.2 try to update it.

Comment: @HusseinAlzand: I have the very latest (non-beta) version. Had tried that already.